# Creating Oscommerce Template

Tags: oscommerce

Where can I find the basic documentation of creating oscommerce 2.3 template? I am new in oscommerce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a 2.3.1 "how to" thread here:

http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/368458-231-a-how-to-road-mapno-questions-just-how-tos-please/

Answer (score 1):

you have to edit in four files

```
includes/header.php,
template_top,
template_bottom,
footer
```

enter your new template data in them and you will see changes on your live site
and one more thing to edit `style.css` you have to enter new css in it and rest `oscommerce` will see it

Answer (score 0):

this link would be helpful and try to check all the discussions. http://forums.oscommerce.com/forum/11-general-support/

while installing any template, try to download full package files and install. read the instructions and there will be some issues regarding versions. Dont install if it is not full package, because it has few lines of code missing.

you can download templates for oscommerce for any version here:

http://addons.oscommerce.com/